# Tried updating from 11.10 to 12.04, gets stuck at boot screen

Tags: upgrade

The update finished, upon restart I get stuck at this:

[image]

- and nothing afterwards. Before I attempt a complete reinstall, are there any other steps I can take?

If I do end up reinstalling, what is the best way to back up my files from the Windows side? As of right now, I cannot view them because Windows sees the folder as a protected recovery partition.

Comment: @karel 11.04 -> 11.10 -> 12.04 ;).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily back up your files on Linux from Windows, as Windows can't read the ext4 filesystem.  You will need to boot into a LiveUSB / LiveCD environment and mount your Linux partition, and copy off data from your Linux partition to your Windows partition that you want to keep via the LiveUSB/LiveCD environment.

From there, if your upgrade failed and gets you stuck in a boot screen, I suggest a clean install of 12.04, then restore your files which you backed up afterwards.

<sub>This is just my suggestion, though, there may be better suggestions from others if you wait a bit more.</sub>